# how to write to div the value of a .net drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to write to a div the dynamic value of a drop down list, like this:

JQuery looks like this

```
$.each($('.shoppingCart_qty-select'), function () {
    var br = document.createElement('br');
    $("#qtyOrderPreview").append($(this).html()).append(br);
    });
```

Markup looks like this

```
<div class="shoppingCart_qtyArea">
<div class="shoppingCart_qtyLabel">QTY</div>
    <select class="shoppingCart_qty-select">
      <option value="1">@group.First().Count</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id ="qtyOrderPreview"></div> <!-- WRITE IT HERE -->
```

But, I cannot see any value being put on the page, although `@group.First().Count` has a value.

What do I have to do different to be able to get the value from the drop down list and place it on the div, using jquery?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is you need to get HTML from `<option>` not `<select>`

```js
$.each($('.shoppingCart_qty-select'), function() {
  var br = document.createElement('br');
  $("#qtyOrderPreview").append($(this).find('option').html()).append(br);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="shoppingCart_qtyArea">
  <div class="shoppingCart_qtyLabel">QTY</div>
  <select class="shoppingCart_qty-select">
    <option value="42">42</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="qtyOrderPreview"></div>
```